# A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the myService service

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I have a C# services which will perform job when timer inside services trigger.
The timer is trigger every 30 minutes. The timer will stop and wait until the task execute completely and then just turn it on and wait for another 30 minutes.

But now, my services get an error log "A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the myService service." in event viewer while actually my process is execute in background thread. The main thread should be can response to control in 30 seconds.

Below is my code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
private void InitDownloadServices()
{
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Interval = 30000;
    timer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ 
    try
    { 
        using (System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(5 ))
        {
            List<Task> _task = new List<Task>();

            for(int i=0; i<= 100; i++)
            { 
                Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                { 
                    concurrencySemaphore.Wait();
                    try
                    {
                        // Long Running process here
                    }
                    catch  {    }
                    finally { concurrencySemaphore.Release(); } 
                }); 
                _task.Add(tsk); 
            }

            while (true)
            {
                bool isRemove = false;
                foreach (Task tsk in _task)
                {
                    if (tsk.IsCompleted) 
                    {
                        isRemove = true;
                        _task.Remove(tsk);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (_task.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!isRemove)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    } 
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
    catch {}
    timer.Enabled=true;
}
```

Comment: in the Long Running Process, I will call COM Component.